# Converting a nested dictionary to a list

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I know there are many dict to list questions on here but I can't quite find the information I need for my situation so I'm asking a new quetion.

Some background: I'm using a hierarchical package for my models and the built-in function which generates the tree structure outputs a nested loop to indicate parents, children, etc. My goal is to keep the logic in views and output a list so that I can simply loop over it in my templates.

Here is my data, in the tree structure:

```
1
-1.1
--1.1.1
---1.1.1.1
--1.1.2
-1.2
--1.2.1
--1.2.2
-1.3
```

Here is the nested dictionary I am getting as a result

```
{
 <Part: 1.1>:
 {
   <Part: 1.1.1>:
     {
       <Part: 1.1.1.1>: {}
     }, 
   <Part: 1.1.2>: {}
 },
 <Part: 1.2>: 
 {
   <Part: 1.2.1>: {},
   <Part: 1.2.2>: {}
 }, 
 <Part: 1.3>: {}
}
```

or if you don't like the way I tried to break it up, here is what I get in a single line:

```
{<Part: 1.1>: {<Part: 1.1.1>: {<Part: 1.1.1.1>: {}}, <Part: 1.1.2>: {}}, <Part: 1.2>: {<Part: 1.2.1>: {}, <Part: 1.2.2>: {}}, <Part: 1.3>: {}}
```

What I'd like is to get:

```
[<Part: 1.1>, <Part: 1.1.1>, <Part: 1.1.1.1>, <Part: 1.1.2>, <Part: 1.2>, <Part: 1.2.2>, <Part: 1.2.1>, <Part: 1.3>,]
```

I've tried just iterating over the key in `dict.items` but then I only get the top level keys `(1.1, 1.2, 1.3)`

What do I need to do to get deeper?

thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think recursion can be your friend :

```
top = {"<Part: 1.1>": {"<Part: 1.1.1>": {"<Part: 1.1.1.1>": {}}, "<Part: 1.1.2>": {}}, "<Part: 1.2>": {"<Part: 1.2.1>": {}, "<Part: 1.2.2>": {}}, "<Part: 1.3>": {}}

 def grab_children(father):
    local_list = []
    for key, value in father.iteritems():
        local_list.append(key)
        local_list.extend(grab_children(value))
    return local_list

print grab_children(top)
```

Comment: Result is wrong, as `'Part: 1.3'` does not appear at the end.

Comment: For Python 3 remove leading space on all function lines, `father.iteritems()` -> father.items(), and add `()` for print.

Answer (score 2):

All of the previous solutions build lots of lists recursively and then extend them back into bigger and bigger lists until you have the final answer. While it works, it is not optimal from a performance perspective, since it creates lots of lists that you really don't need, and involves extending the same items many times into their parent lists. Some solutions also forget to sort on the keys.

```
top = {"<Part: 1.1>": {"<Part: 1.1.1>": {"<Part: 1.1.1.1>": {}}, "<Part: 1.1.2>": {}}, "<Part: 1.2>": {"<Part: 1.2.1>": {}, "<Part: 1.2.2>": {}}, "<Part: 1.3>": {}}

def flatten(d, ret=None):
    if ret is None:
        ret = []
    for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
        ret.append(k)
        if v:
            flatten(v, ret)
    return ret

def test():
    flatten(top)
```

According to `python -m timeit -s "import flatten" "flatten.test()"`, this method uses 8.57 usecs per loop, compared with 14.4 usecs per loop for Cédrics answer, when updated to also sort the output properly (`for key, value in sorted(father.items()):`)

Answer (score 1):

Inception... er, I mean, recursion. Try this:

```
def recurse(dict):
    result = []
    for key in dict:
        result.append(key)
        result.extend(recurse(dict[key]))
    return result
```

Comment: I did this in the shell and it returned a couple hundred values instead of 10? Did I miss something?

Comment: Result is wrong, as `'Part: 1.3'` does not appear at the end.

Comment: and it keeps adding onto itself the more times it executes.

Comment: It works just fine for me. Maybe you accidentally declared `result` as a global?

Comment: I don't know what I did the first time, but it does work just fine

Answer (score 0):

This problem can't be solved by simple iteration over the dictionary. You need a type of algorithm called [recursive descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

```
def getKeys(D, answer):
    if not D:
        return
    else:
        for k in D:
            answer.append(k)
            getKeys(D[k], answer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {"<Part: 1.1>": {"<Part: 1.1.1>": {"<Part: 1.1.1.1>": {}}, "<Part: 1.1.2>": {}}, "<Part: 1.2>": {"<Part: 1.2.1>": {}, "<Part: 1.2.2>": {}}, "<Part: 1.3>": {}}
    answer = []
    getKeys(d, answer)
    print answer
```

This has been tested and is working

Hope this helps

Comment: The `for` loop will only do one iteration, since it contains a `return`. Also [modifying a default argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) is never a good idea...

Comment: Yeah, the return wasn't the best move ever made. It's fixed now, though

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mihai's answer: you need to sort your keys, else you will probably have problems:

```
def recurse(d):
    result = []
    for key in sorted(d.keys()):
        result.append(key)
        result.extend(recurse(d[key]))
    return result
```

Comment: getting a KeyError in the 5th line for <Part 1.1.1>