# How to convert json to tree in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, tree

I have a json file like below:

```
{
    "App Builder": {
        "utterance": [
            "create an app",
            "create app for me",
            "can you create an application?"
        ],
        "question": [
            "Do you want to create application through UI or API Builder?",
            "Do you want to try our getting started page?"
        ],
        "children": [{
                "API Builder": {
                    "utterance": [
                        "create an app using API Buider",
                        "make an application using API Builder",
                        "create API Builder application"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "UI": {
                    "utterance": [
                        "create an app using user interface",
                        "make an application using UI",
                        "create UI application"
                    ],
                    "question": [
                            "Do you want to create application through Template or UI Builder?",
                            "Do you want to try our getting started page?"
                        ]

                        ,
                    "children": [{
                            "UI Builder": {
                                "utterance": [
                                    "create an app using UI Buider",
                                    "make an application using UI Builder",
                                    "create UI Builder application"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "Template": {
                                "utterance": [
                                    "create an app using Template",
                                    "make an application using Template",
                                    "create Template application"
                                ],
                                "question": [
                                    "Do you want to create application through Angular or React or PHP?",
                                    "Do you want to try our getting started page?"
                                ],
                                "children": [{
                                    "Angular": {
                                        "utterance": [
                                            "create an app using Angular",
                                            "make an application using Angular template",
                                            "create Angular application"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "React": {
                                        "utterance": [
                                            "create an app using React",
                                            "make an application using template React",
                                            "create React application"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "PHP": {
                                        "utterance": [
                                            "create an app using PHP",
                                            "make an application using template PHP",
                                            "create PHP application"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

From this, I want to find all walks of each node. By using the following code, I somehow managed to get the result given below.

```
edges = []
leaves = []
nodes = []
def get_edges(treedict, parent=None):
    try:
        name = next(iter(treedict.keys()))
        nodes.append(name)
        if parent is not None:
            edges.append((parent, name))
        for item in treedict[name]["children"]:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                get_edges(item, parent=name)
            else:
                edges.append((name, item))

    except KeyError as e:
        leaves.append(name)
        pass
```

Intermediate result:

```
print(edges)

[('App Builder', 'API Builder'), ('App Builder', 'UI'), ('UI', 'UI Builder'), ('UI', 'Template'), ('Template', 'Angular'), ('Template', 'React'), ('Template', 'PHP')]
```

Now I want to find the path of each nodes. i.e.,

```
['App Builder', 'App Builder/API Builder', 'App Builder/UI', 'App Builder/UI/UI Builder', 'App Builder/UI/Template',
         'App Builder/UI/Template/Angular', 'App Builder/UI/Template/React', 'App Builder/UI/Template/PHP']
```

How can I get these values?

Can I get this path from `edges` only by converting the list into tree?

Any other better approach for this problem?

any help would be appreciable.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5938125/8353711) SO post could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to generate a list of strings, that represent the path to each node connected through `"children"` to other nodes, with the path being made up of the keys of the nodes.

```py
import json


def paths(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        yield key
        if 'children' in value:
            for child in value['children']:
                for path in paths(child):
                    yield f'{key}/{path}'


with open('your_data.json') as f:
    print(list(paths(json.load(f))))
```

Note that `paths()` is a generator, yielding one result at a time, which is why the result of `paths()` is wrapped in `list()` before printing the result.

Comment: Hi, can u add depth here?

Comment: What do you mean exactly, @DanialShabbir? The depth of each path would simply be the number of elements when splitting the path over the path separator? Or do you mean some other depth?

Comment: Yeah, got that. Thanks for replying.